# tkinter get keystrokes from outside window?

Tags: python, tkinter, key, keystroke

How do I get the users keystrokes that take place in external applications, not connected with the python window, using python?

Meaning, say I want to track what keys someone is typing in another program, or any program.

How can this be done with tkinter?

Comment: So a keylogger?  I know python has libraries for that and you can run the keylogger in its own thread and then send commands back to tkinter when a condition is met.

Comment: Do you want to make a hot key function in your tkinter App?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I want to make an app like use in screen recorders that shows what key is being pressed anywhere on the computer for recording and streaming purposes

Comment: learn something about ``pynput`` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with tkinter. You will have to use some external platform-specific library to listen for keystrokes in any window other than the windows controlled by tkinter.

Comment: can you do it with python in general though?

Comment: @bluejayke: no. It will require a platform-specific library.

Comment: ya but what? (for windows)